# Fast/Easy way to run a method based on a condition

Tags: c#, operators

Is there a way to run a method based on a conditional statement like a null-coalescing/ternary operator?

Sometimes, I have something like this in my code:

```
if(Extender.GetSetting<string>("User") == null)
{
     ConfigureApp();
}
else
{
     loadUser();
}
```

Is there a way I can have something like:

```
Extender.GetSettings<string>("User")?? ConfigureApp() : loadUser();
```

***OR***

```
Extender.GetSettings<string>("User") == null ? ConfigureApp() : loadUser();
```

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance, but wouldn't the 3rd one work?

Comment: Don't do it, *clear* is better than *short* when it comes to code. This might look nice now, but if you return to it next year you're going to think "holy mother of source code this is nasty". that's because you'll have forgotten what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @npinti The 3rd one will work only when `ConfigureApp` and `loadUser()` both return values, and these values are of compatible types. You may need to insert a cast. If one of the two or both are `void`, this will not compile.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: But isn't the OP checking if a given value is null and then call what seem to be void methods?

Comment: @npinti Correct, both methods appear `void`. That is why the third snippet did not compile for the OP, and so he's asking how to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible, but it is not readable. The `if` statement is much better.

```
(Extender.GetSettings<string>("User") == null ? (Action)ConfigureApp : loadUser)();
```

Comment: Yuk. +1 for the warning about readability. Stick with an `if`.

Comment: I would add a recommendation to read Steve McConnell's "Code Complete" book.

Comment: Thanks! So basically this is impossible in C# 2.0?

Comment: Why so? Because `Action` isn't defined? It's trivial to define your own delegate to replace it.

Comment: @dashblinkenlight, I'm not positive but I don't think your cast of the method group will compile in this case.  I know it works for passing in arguments, but this looks a little off

Comment: @rtuner Why, no, it is not impossible, it's just that the syntax is a lot messier. You'd have to define a delegate type (I don't remember if there was an `Action` delegate before 2.0) and wrap each function in a delegate. But after that everything would work in the same way.

Comment: @smartcaveman I wasn't positive either, so I verified that the snippet compiles before posting the answer :)

Comment: @dashblinkenlight, that's what I get for posting from my android

Comment: Just for the sake of others, I tried compiling this in .NET Framework 2.0 it didn't compile, then I tried 3.0, and it finally compiled in 4.0, so I guess it's only available in 3.5+. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can write a line like:

```
 (Extender.GetSetting<string>("User") == null ? (Action)(()=>ConfigureApp()) : (Action)(()=>loadUser()) )();
```

However, the only difference this code adds to your `if` statement is slower performance due to the construction of the delegates.  It is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

***Simple, fast and short way.***

```
if (Extender.GetSetting<string>("User") == null) ConfigureApp(); else loadUser();
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up using something like this even though this was not the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

may be something like:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        String s = "";
        Launcher(s == "user1", A1, A2);
        s = "user1";
        Launcher(s == "user1", A1, A2);
    }

    static void Launcher(Boolean b, Action a1, Action a2) {
        if (b) { a1(); } else { a2(); }
    }

    static void A1() {
        Console.WriteLine("action 1");
    }

    static void A2() {
        Console.WriteLine("action 2");
    }
}
```